# Installed snaps fail to run on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, snap

I have several snaps installed:
$ snap list

```
Name               Version                 Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
core               16-2.39                 6964  stable    canonical✓    core
core18             20190508                970   stable    canonical✓    base
gimp               2.10.12                 189   stable    snapcrafters  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-16-g2287c87         1198  stable    canonical✓    -
krita              4.2.0                   48    stable    krita✓        -
spotify            1.1.5.153.gf614956d-16  35    stable    spotify✓      -
```

If I try to run one from the launcher, the program icon appears, flashes slowly, then dissapears.  This happens for krita, gimp, and spotify (all that I have tried so far)

If I type "gimp" into the command line, I get: `bash: gimp: command not found`
 which doesn't seem correct...

How can I run my snap apps?

How do I get these to work?

Edit, I tried it with a non-sudo user and I get this:

```
:~$ gimp
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```